# How to set mutually exclusive probabilities in Problog?

Tags: prolog, logic, probability

A person `X` can either be `inpatient` or `outpatient`. 
Given the fact `location(X,outpatient)` how can Problog infer that the probability of `location(X,inpatient)` is 0?

For example I want a side effect of:

```
person(1).
location(1,inpatient).
dependent(1,opioids).
receive(1,clonidine).
query(detoxification(1,opioids,success)).
```

to be an inference that `location(1,outpatient)` has zero probability.

If I write `location(X,outpatient);location(X,inpatient).`, all queries return both with a probability of 1.

If I write `P::location(X,outpatient);(1-P)::location(X,inpatient).` that gives an error because I haven't specified a value for `P`. If I specify a value for `P`, that value is never updated (as expected because Prolog treats variables as *algebraic* variables and I haven't told Problog to update `P`.

If I write `location(X,outpatient) :- \+ location(X,inpatient).` I create a negative cycle, which I have to if I am to specify the inverse goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

```
P::property(X,location,inpatient);(1-P)::property(X,location, outpatient) :- 
    inpatient(X),
    P is 1. 

P::property(X,location,outpatient);(1-P)::property(X,location, inpatient) :- 
    outpatient(X),
    P is 1. 

P::inpatient(X);(1-P)::outpatient(X) :- 
    property(X,location,inpatient),
    P is 1.

P::outpatient(X);(1-P)::inpatient(X) :-
    property(X,location,outpatient),
    P is 1.
```

This binds `inpatient/1` to `property/3` for the property of `location` with value `inpatient`.